# forEach is Not a Function Error in JQuery from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I'm working on accessing elements inside a JSON string, but I'm receiving an error of

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Object.keys(...).Each is not a function success@http....

Here is my code:

```
response =JSON.stringify('[{"file": "app.dll", "fields": {"name": "Misc App", "rank": 1}}]');
response = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(response);

response.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

Bonus points for demonstrating how to display the names and values of the elements in the array!

Comment: Retagging to JS because there is no jQuery in the question

Comment: You ```stringify``` a string. Guess what is the result datatype ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Many things can be serialized in Javascript, *including strings*. For example, if you stringify:

```
const foo = 'foo';
JSON.stringify(foo);
```

you get

```
"foo"
```

Here, because you're stringifying a string the same way:

```
response =JSON.stringify('[{"file": "app.dll", "fields": {"name": "Misc App", "rank": 1}}]');
```

When you parse it later, you get back *the original string*, as intended.

Either don't stringify it at all initially:

```js
let response = '[{"file": "app.dll", "fields": {"name": "Misc App", "rank": 1}}]';
response = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(response);

response.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

Or, if you really have to, parse it *twice*:

```js
let response = JSON.stringify('[{"file": "app.dll", "fields": {"name": "Misc App", "rank": 1}}]');
response = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response));
console.log(response);

response.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

(but that's a very weird solution - it'd be better by far not to stringify the string in the first place, since it's already in parseable JSON format)